# Output screen flashes and disappears suddenly in VS2013?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world");

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

I am writing a simple hello world application using C language but when i run the program the output screen flashes and disappears suddenly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getch() ( even though _getch() should be used ) will read the stdin. But it is possible that the compiler is optimizing the function out, and it never gets called ending the program.

edit:
The function getch() is deprecated and _getch() should be used, according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235446.aspx).